# Autohotkey: Check visibility of a control identified by its text

Tags: automation, controls, autohotkey

I just started playing around with AutoHotKey today but got stuck at identifying a control by its text. I want to check whether a specific control is visible. WindowSpy tells about the control:
   Control under Mouse Position:

ClassNN:    ClaButton_01000000H58

Text:    Gehe

This works fine:

```
ControlGet, xxx, Visible, ClaButton_01000000H58, A
MsgBox The visibility is %xxx%
```

But I want to use the control text. And this always returns an empty result:

```
ControlGet, xxx, Visible, Gehe, A
MsgBox The visibility is %xxx%
```

I tried it also with:
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow
but my attempt to adress the Button by its ButtonText don't work. Does somebody can see my Error or is there an other way?

Many Thx in advance

Comment: See [**ControlGetText**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGetText.htm)

Comment: maybe some spaces missing? it looks like it *should* work

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.
I recently tried this. The only problem is that if the control is visible or hidden, it always returns: `1`.

```
ControlGet, OutputVar, Visible,, %MyProgress%
```

MyProgress is the variable name of my progress bar which I hide after creating the GUI.